# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method is not implemented

Tags: selenium, appium-android

I am trying to perform read text from Android - Chrome Browser using JavascriptExecutor.

My code:

```
String videoDurationValue = javascriptExecutor.executeScript("var value = \"document.evaluate(\"//*[@id='my-video']/div[5]/div[7]/div\", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.innerHTML\", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.innerHTML; return value.stringValue;").toString();
```

But getting error -

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method is not implemented
```

Appium version 1.8.1

Need help to fix this issue.

Comment: how did you initialize javascriptExecutor and driver? If you are trying to execute JS on native elements/driver, it's not going to work. See https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/212

Comment: error caused after updating client side libraries? if so, please revert

Comment: Here is my code:

AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver = new AppiumDriver<WebElement>(
                        new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilitiesUtils.getAndroidCapability()); 
      
JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

Answer (score 0):

Correct your syntax as below and try .

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
Object videoDurationValue = js.executeScript("var value = document.evaluate(\"//*[@id='my-video']/div[5]/div[7]/div\",document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null ); return value.stringValue;");
System.out.println(videoDurationValue.toString());
```

Comment: It did not work - org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method is not implemented. When I do driver.getPageSource() ==> I get page source in XML format. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hierarchy rotation="0">..

Comment: @Deepak, it seems problem is in `driver.getPageSource()` with appium there is nothing to do with the xpath. refer this one https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/7235 So debug the same and update the question.

Comment: Hi Narendra, can we execute JavascriptExecutor commands on Page which is not developed using HTML tags. Instead it is developed using XML. In find element I use By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='Play Video']"). If yes what should I pass in executor HTML XPATH or NATIVE app XPATH